# Ubuntu 19.04 on first boot with disabled wifi , doesn't start the wifi usb adapter (module?)

Tags: networking, wireless, mediatek

When i turn my pc for the first time ubuntu 19.04 will boot without my wifi detected/enabled.
I need to run these commands to turn on the wifi on every boot !!!

```
sudo modprobe -r mt7601u
sudo modprobe -i mt7601u
sudo modprobe -r mt7601u
sudo modprobe -i mt7601u
```

Something is wrong with the kernel i guess cause i never had any problems with my wifi adapter.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status`.

Comment: Now i'm on good old lts nvidia, 430.09, 4.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed          Bus 003 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter

Comment: Please don't use the comments to show data... edit your question... copy/paste the data there, and then select that data, and then click the {} icon to format the data. From what I think I see, the wireless driver didn't get built for 19.04... but let me recheck after you update your question. Thanks. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.